# C# for telecom applications?

Tags: c#, asn.1, telecommunication

who is using .net technologies for telecom applications? Are there any resources for this?
I am interested in topics as SS7 signaling, ASN.1, MML Commands etc.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you've mentioned clearly as C# and .Net platform, but here's a little tidbit if you're interested: The Erlang/OTP (Open Telecommunication Platform) was specifically built by Ericsson for building large scale telecom applications. You might wanna have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will face the same problem with .NET for realtime applications as the financial industry does with java and .NET.

The problem is the garbage collection, it might kick in anytime, suspending your program and performing a collection cycle. As this is (basically) unpredictable all garabgecollected langugages aren't well suited for realtime applications that work with high throughput.

If your application is only on the operation support side, it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk is a good choice for you needs. It is open source and free to use. Many large telecom providers are using Asterisk. There are many ways to integrate with it using C#. The Asterisk Management Interface would be your best choice.

Check out http://www.asterisk.org/ for more information.